# Authentication Fails When Cloning TFS repo with Git

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-code

I have always created local repositories using this command:

```
git clone http://TFSServer:8080/tfs/Scripts/_git/ProjectName
```

However, when I do it at the moment I get this message:

> Cloning into 'ProjectName' ...
>
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://TFSServer:8080/tfs/Scripts/_git/ProjectName/'

---

When starting up Visual Studio Code I see this error:

> unable to get local issuer certificate

and when trying to push to TFS from VSCode (which I have always been able to do in the past), I see this error:

> Authentication failed on the git remote

---

After checking the repo permissions, I can see that I have full permissions:

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It turns out that this only started happening after I needed to change Windows logon password.

The password was updated locally and on the TFS server, but not in the cached credentials for git.

#### Fix

`Control Panel` -> `Credential Manager` -> `Generic Credentials`

Then update the password for `git:http://ServerName:1234/`

Now I can successfully access the repo from command line and VS Code.

Comment: This fixed things for me as well. I am not sure why the credentials didn't also get automatically updated upon windows password change though.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the Git repository 'ProjectName' permissions to see whether you have the **Read** permission, or grant your account the **Read** permssion:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was resolved changing settings in Visual Studio.  I got the instructions from this post on Microsoft's Developer Community.

[Git Clone from TFS: Authentication error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/273553/view.html)

Depending on what kind of secure channel are you using to connect to your repo the solution for this issue could be different.  In my case I'm using OpenSSL and the steps to fix the problem are ase follows:

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Click on Team Explorer > Settings > Global Settings
3. Change the Cryptographic network provider to OpenSSL.

Answer (score -1):

I can almost guarantee you that the URL you're using is wrong.

It should typically be: 
`git clone http://<tfs uri>/tfs/<team project collection name>/<team project name>/_git/<repo name>`

Comment: I have always been able to clone my repos using the format in my question. In fact, when I select `Clone` on the TFS web interface, I am given this url: `http://appdev:8080/tfs/Applications/_git/DeleteFiles`, which is in the form `http://<tfs uri>/tfs/<team project collection name>/_git/<team project name>`.